# Why is there a status message "302 Found" on top of the site?

Tags: redirect

I'm confused about current state of my website. Whole website is working fine but on the top of the site it shows a weird message. Please see the image below:

[image]

Why this message shows up? Is my site has been hacked or is this a virus? My wordpress version is 3.9. Please help.

Comment: 302 is related with some redirection. may try disabling plugins.

Comment: Are you using Apache rewrite or similar for custom permalinks? Which permalink option are you using, and what's your webserver configuration?